# Message display in administration Repport and MySQL SELECT different

Tags: log-messages

When look at log details from http://website/admin/reports/dblog/event/12599, it shows the following message.

> Starting execution of search_cron(), execution of node_cron() took 5.26ms.

When I query the database table used, I get the following.

> Starting execution of @module_cron(), execution of @module_previous_cron() took @time.

How do I get, querying the database, the same message I see on the log?

Comment: That's because those are placeholders that get rendered correctly in the UI. That's how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message shown in the log is the output of `t('Starting execution of @module_cron(), execution of @module_previous_cron() took @time.')` (or `new TranslatableMarkup('Starting execution of @module_cron(), execution of @module_previous_cron() took @time.')` while in the database you find the string passed to `t()` or `new TranslatableMarkup()`.

To get the string output in the log, you need to find the list of the placeholder values passed to `t()`, which are in the same database table.
That is essentially what [`DbLogController::eventDetails()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21dblog%21src%21Controller%21DbLogController.php/function/DbLogController%3A%3AeventDetails/8.9.x), the controller showing pages like /admin/reports/dblog/event/12599 does.

```php
  $dblog = $this->database->query('SELECT w.*, u.uid FROM {watchdog} w LEFT JOIN {users} u ON u.uid = w.uid WHERE w.wid = :id', [
    ':id' => $event_id,
  ])
    ->fetchObject();
  if (empty($dblog)) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
  }
  $build = [];
  $severity = RfcLogLevel::getLevels();
  $message = $this->formatMessage($dblog);
```

In the URL you shown, `$event_id` is 12599.
`formatMessage()` is a public method of `DbLogController`. You can copy the code from that method, or instantiate the controller in the appropriate way. For example, the following function would return the message with the placeholders replaced by their values.

```php
function mymodule_get_log_message($event_id) {
  $message = '';
  $dblog = \Drupal::database->query('SELECT w.*, u.uid FROM {watchdog} w LEFT JOIN {users} u ON u.uid = w.uid WHERE w.wid = :id', [
    ':id' => $event_id,
  ])
    ->fetchObject();
  if (!empty($dblog)) {
    // Check for required properties.
    if (isset($dblog->message, $dblog->variables)) {
      $variables = @unserialize($dblog->variables);

    // Messages without variables or user specified text.
    if ($variables === NULL) {
      $message = Xss::filterAdmin($dblog->message);
    }
    elseif (!is_array($variables)) {
      $message = new TranslatableMarkup('Log data is corrupted and cannot be unserialized: @message', ['@message' => Xss::filterAdmin($dblog->message)]);
    }
    else {
      // Ensure backtrace strings are properly formatted.
      if (isset($variables['@backtrace_string'])) {
        $variables['@backtrace_string'] = new FormattableMarkup('<pre class="backtrace">@backtrace_string</pre>', $variables);
      }
      $message = (Xss::filterAdmin($dblog->message), $variables);
    }
  }

  return $message
}
```

As usual, where possible, use Dependency Injection instead of `\Drupal`. When sub-classing some classes, a `t()` method is available; that should be used instead of `t()` or `new TranslatableMarkup()`.